# How to use *ngFor twice in single html

Tags: angular

[Here is my html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3sj2.png)

I want to use pagination in this case. Is it even possible ?

Comment: Hi Edi, welcome to stack overflow. Why not? Are you getting some error? NgFor can be used any number of times you want. Also please never post an image of your code. Include the relevant part of it on you question surrounded by triple backticks: ```

Answer (score 1):

u can use this construction:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="">
    <ng-container *ngFor="">
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: But i can't but <app-item> in <ng-container> . I've tried few constructions with ng-container but still not working properly. Does not limit ads to 6 per pange. They became x2 or even x3.

Comment: @EdiMustanski u asked how to use ngFor twice, ng-container allow this without any html. so fix logic